# How to correctly authenticate User from an Angular app at an Spring Security Backend

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, angular8, angular-httpclient

I am trying to authenticate my Angular 8 application at my Spring Boot 2.1 backend which is secured by Spring Security. The users request is checked against the Active Directory. If the user can be authenticated, I want to return a JSON response containig username and authorities. Adittionally i want to set a cookie. 
I managed to get around the cors problem and I am able to get the correct response using Postman. 
But I can not get the correct information in my Angular application.

### Spring Boot

**LoginController.java**

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true")
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    SecurityContext context;
    Authentication authentication;
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;
    String cips_authorities = "";

    @GetMapping(value = "/loginPage")
    public String loginPage() {
        String loginForm = "<html >\n " +
        "<head></head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "   <h1>Login</h1>\n" +
                "   <form name='f' action=\"/login/loginPage\" method='post'>\n" +  // @{/login}
                "      <table>\n" +
                "         <tr>\n" +
                "            <td>User:</td>\n" +
                "            <td><input type='text' name='username' id='username' value=''></td>\n" +
                "         </tr>\n" +
                "         <tr>\n" +
                "            <td>Password:</td>\n" +
                "            <td><input type='password' name='password' id='password' /></td>\n" +
                "         </tr>\n" +
                "         <tr>\n" +
                "            <td><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" /></td>\n" +
                "         </tr>\n" +
                "      </table>\n" +
                "  </form>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";

        return loginForm;
    }
    @GetMapping(value = "/successful")
    public String successful(HttpServletResponse response) {

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        authentication = context.getAuthentication();

        grantedAuthorities = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>) authentication.getAuthorities();
        cips_authorities = "";
        if (grantedAuthorities.toString().contains("CIPS_INVOICE")) {
            cips_authorities += ", \"CIPS_INVOICE\"";
        }
        if (grantedAuthorities.toString().contains("CIPS_STATS")) {
            cips_authorities += ", \"CIPS_STATS\"";
        }
        if (cips_authorities.length() > 2) {
            cips_authorities = "[" + cips_authorities.substring(2) + "]";
        }

        String userInformation = "{" +
                "\"userName\":\"" + authentication.getName() + "\"," +
                "\"authorities\":" + cips_authorities + "," +
                "\"authenticated\":\"" + authentication.isAuthenticated() + "\"" +
                "}";

        return userInformation;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/logout")
    public String logout() {
        context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

        String error = "{" +
                "\"userName\":\"" + authentication.getName() + "\"," +
                "\"authenticated\":\"" + authentication.isAuthenticated() + "\"" +
                "}";

        return error;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/active")
    public String active() {
        context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        authentication = context.getAuthentication();

        String userInformation = "{" +
                "userName:" + authentication.getName() + "," +
                "authenticated:" + authentication.isAuthenticated() +
                "}";

        return userInformation;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/loggedOut")
    public String logedout() {
        context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        authentication = context.getAuthentication();

        String userInformation = "{" +
                "\"session\":\"logged out\"" +
                "}";

        return userInformation;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/failed")
    public String failed() {
        context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        authentication = context.getAuthentication();

        String error = "{" +
                "\"userName\":\"" + authentication.getName() + "\"," +
                "\"authenticated\":\"" + authentication.isAuthenticated() + "\"" +
                "}";

        return error;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/invalidSession")
    public String invalidSession() {
        String error = "{" +
                "\"session\":\"invalid\"" +
                "}";
        return error;
    }
}
```

**BasicConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/login/successful", true)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login/loginPage")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .failureUrl("/login/failed")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .x509()
                .disable();

        http.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/login/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/loggedOut")
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);


        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
        http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login/invalidSession");
        http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource () {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-   token"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

### Postman Results

```
Request: 
Headers: 
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:
  username: <my-username>
  password: <my-password>

Response:
Headers:
  Date: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 06:44:50 GMT
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
  Content-Typ: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block"
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  Content-Lenght: 91
Cookies:
  Name: JSESSIONID
  Value: node01hidiu16ks9zn1owypmdrimsxw3.node0
Body:
  {"userName":"<my-username>","authorities":["CIPS_INVOICE", "CIPS_STATS"],"authenticated":"true"}
```

### Angular Results

```
Code for the request: 
const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('username', username);
    formdata.append('password', password);

 this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/login/loginPage`, formdata, {responseType: 'text'})
               .subscribe(res => {
                 console.log('response', res);
               });

Response:
response {"userName":"anonymousUser","authorities":,"authenticated":"true"}
```

My Question: Why can't I get the information from the AD when I send a request from my Angular application although I can get them if I send a request via Postman?
And how can I change that?

Comment: Could you post the network log in the browser when you send the request with angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem: 
It was a combination of server and client errors.

I changed the following:

#### LoginController.java:

In the `successfull` method, I removed the `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` call.

#### BasicConfiguration.java

In the `corsConfigurationSource` Bean, I changed the AllowedOrigin policy:
`corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"))`

and added the AllowCredentials policy:
`corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true)`

#### Angular

I changed the post call to include withCredentials: true

```
this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/login/loginPage`, formdata,
                          {withCredentials: true})
               .subscribe(res => {
                 console.log(res);
               });
```

Thanks to everyone who answered and tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell angular to get full response not just body.
By default angular httpClient return only body. In order to get full response you need to add
 `observe: 'response'` in httpOptions something like this

```
var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let httpOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true, observe: 'response' });

 return this.http.post(url, data, httpOptions)
   .subscribe(res => {
             console.log('response', res);
           });
 });
```

for more details see [angular docs - reading full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do the trick. I get the following headers: 
`content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8`, `expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` and the body `{"userName":"anonymousUser","authorities":,"authenticated":"true"}`

Comment: I edited my answer. It's all about configuring httpOptions right. You can add multiple headers and also use option 'withCredentials' : true to get cookies and more headers...

Comment: I tried out your suggestions but it didn't change anything unfortunately. 
I don't understand why the Postman request returns the correct response but the angular request does not although they contain the same header..